# Disable script only on certain element id in Wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using other plugin to manage tables and make them responsive and sortable inside my plugin. It works like a charm, but now I am in need of making a custom table, that doesn't need to be sortable. Is there any way to disable script (I listed all script ids and know which `.js` this plugin calls) only on this specific table element id? I can override `.css`, but I am having trouble with disabling sorting only for this table, since it's javascript.

I looked at `wp_dequeue_script('');`, but unfortunately, I have more tables than just this custom one. If I use it on the same wp page, dequeueing script would disable sorting for all the other tables too...

Is there any way to override this? Or can I somehow just disable click event on this element?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is disable `.click()` events, you can achieve it with CSS.

```html
<div style="pointer-events: none;"> 
    <p> This element has no click() event </p>
<div>
```

Comment: Great, this works. But what would be a way around if I wanted to have my custom onclick event that overrides sorting? Thanks, I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: For that, you would need to use a `document.getElementById(id)` in JS to get the table element. Then use `tableElement.onclick = function(){ /* override script */ };`.